# (restful) parse json with JSONValue.parse java error

Tags: java, json

```
public String GetAllProjectByNameFileExcept(String NameFile)
    {
        JSONObject output_json = new JSONObject();
        ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();
        DB db = null;
        try 
        {
            db = MONGODB.GetMongoDB();
            DBCollection collLocal = db.getCollection("local");
            BasicDBObject objek_db = new BasicDBObject();
            BasicDBObject objek_db2 = new BasicDBObject();
            objek_db.put("$ne", NameFile);
            objek_db2.put("_id",objek_db);
            DBCursor cursor = collLocal.find(objek_db2);
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                List.add(cursor.next().get("_id").toString());
            }

            if (List.size() == 0)
            {
                output_json.put("code", 0);
                output_json.put("message", "Not Found");
                output_json.put("data", null);
            }else
            {
                output_json.put("code", 1);
                output_json.put("message", "Success");
                output_json.put("data", List);
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            output_json.put("code", -1);
            output_json.put("message",e.toString());
        }

        return output_json.toString();  
    }
```

i have function GetAllProjectByNameFileExcept return value :

```
{"code":1,"data":[A11.2011.05900.pdf, A11.2011.05930.pdf, A11.2011.05931.pdf, A11.2011.05932.pdf],"message":"Success"}
```

type data [A11.2011.05900.pdf,...,n.pdf] is ArrayList String 
i called this function in other function :

```js
String list = this.GetAllProjectByNameFileExcept(NameFile);
output_json.put("result", list);
```

i was checked output :

```
{"result":"{\"code\":1,\"data\":[A11.2011.05900.pdf, A11.2011.05930.pdf, A11.2011.05931.pdf, A11.2011.05932.pdf],\"message\":\"Success\"}"}
```

but if *list* parse with this code:

```
JSONObject FileData = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(list);
```

always getting errors

```
java.lang.Error: Error: could not match input
org.json.simple.JSONValue.parse(Unknown Source)
service.CrawLocal.PlagiarismCheck(CrawLocal.java:276)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

code to parse in other function sucess i think errors because ArrayList String type data.. what should I do?

Comment: I think you have some issue with your method. you need to show the code for your method "GetAllProjectByNameFileExcept(NameFile);" to see what exactly it is.

Comment: format your json string to have double quotes wrap around your array like ["A11.2011.05900.pdf", "A11.2011.05930.pdf",...]. I believe that is the issue as your current json string is invalid. check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON string is wrong. your inner array "data" should have be an array of strings. means you have missed the double/ single quotes wrapping the values.
check for the json validity using this [link](http://jsonlint.com/)

your correct JSON output should look like this:

```js
{
  "code": 1,
  "data": [
    "A11.2011.05900.pdf",
    "A11.2011.05930.pdf",
    "A11.2011.05931.pdf",
    "A11.2011.05932.pdf"
  ],
  "message": "Success"
}
```

try to format it like above and then parse it.
you can parse it online and check the validity in this link:
[online json parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Comment: thanks @NomeshDeSilva output function json was wrong when i check validity, but how i make format ["foo",..,"foo"]. i found errors because output json like this {"code" : "{\"message\":\"Success\"}"} so parser can't resolve. So i change my method. thanks for your respon and validity json information :D

Comment: please post your latest method, and if my reply really guided you, give some votes pls bro !

Comment: @Orlando, what is the output of this line "cursor.next().get("_id")"  and also I suggest to change your List declaration to below:  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: i was tried but i'm sorry @NomeshDeSilva i can't because my reputation still 3. minimum15 to votes.